# Error 'No Primary or Candidate Keys in the referenced table' when primary table has (Identity (1, 1))

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_Actor 
(
    ActorId INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #Temp_Actor DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO #Temp_Actor DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO #Temp_Actor DEFAULT VALUES;

CREATE TABLE #Temp_ThirdParty 
(
    ThirdPartyActorId INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ThirdPartyActorId 
        PRIMARY KEY (ThirdPartyActorId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_ThirdPartyActorId_ActorId 
        FOREIGN KEY (ThirdPartyActorId) REFERENCES #Temp_Actor (ActorId)
)
```

I get an error:

> There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table '#TempActor'

Surely `ActorId` is the primary key?!

Comment: No, `IDENTITY` does not mean `PRIMARY KEY`.  You need `ActorId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY`.  `IDENTITY` is just an autoincrement mechanism.  It's often used as a PK, but is not by definition.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem. `IDENTITY` does not make a column `UNIQUE` nor a `PRIMARY KEY`. Defining the column as `UNIQUE` or as the `PRIMARY` key makes it `UNIQUE` or a `PRIMARY KEY`. This is well documented in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks) section of the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it out below.

The missing part is here:

```
ActorId INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY)
```

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp_Actor;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp_ThirdParty;

CREATE TABLE #Temp_Actor (ActorId INT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO #Temp_Actor Default values;
INSERT INTO #Temp_Actor Default values;
INSERT INTO #Temp_Actor Default values;

Create TABLE #Temp_ThirdParty (ThirdPartyActorId INT NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT PK_ThirdPartyActorId PRIMARY KEY (ThirdPartyActorId)
, CONSTRAINT FK_ThirdPartyActorId_ActorId FOREIGN KEY (ThirdPartyActorId) REFERENCES #Temp_Actor(ActorId));
```